# Is it possible to add a custom field to change theme fonts dynamically in WordPress' backend?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, function, fonts

I want to add a custom function in my WordPress Theme which I am developing, which makes it possible to change the font in the style-sheet or override it. I am making a custom theme panel and want to have also this as a customization.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use google fonts API. Add select option using google font for body, heading tags,p tag and others. Also add a textarea where user will add there css code for style. After user save button click you need to generate a css file in the css folder in specific file. Load this style by wp_enqueue_script function. Thats all.

Comment: Sorry but I am a beginner and I need this for a school project, I also have searched on the Internet but didn't find anything relevant. If you could show me an example, that would be awesome!

Answer (score 0):

It would depend on the mechanism which you use to load the fonts, but it should be relatively easy. You could make a field using native custom fields, or ACF (which I think is much better), and then just inject this field into the header. There are a lot of variations you could use, but you could just have the field accept a link for a stylesheet or a script, or both. You could also inject it using wp_enqueue_script.

The slightly more complex part may be ensuring that the font stack for different weights and styles is correct given that different webfont services use slightly different syntaxes for their font stacks. You could have some sort of menu to select the foundry from which the fonts are fetched, and change the syntax based on that, allowing them to enter a font stack themselves, but depending on how technical the user is, this might not work too well. It may be easier to actually have a select menu of somewhat varying fonts from which the user can choose, that way you can circumvent the user error that might occur with non-technical users trying to implement any random font.